# How to check an Ajax request in cakephp?

Tags: ajax, cakephp

How to check an Ajax request in cakephp?

Answer (score 49):

Depends on the version of cake.

1.3.x:

```
$this->RequestHandler->isAjax();
```

2.x || 3.x

```
$this->request->is('ajax');
```

Comment: Found this answer in Google kind sir.

Answer (score 17):

- You need to enable the RequestHandler component

`var $components = array('RequestHandler');`

- Then you check if its an ajax request in your controllers with:

`$this->RequestHandler->isAjax()`

You can find more information about the [RequestHandler component here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/350/Obtaining-Request-Information)

Answer (score 10):

this question is an older one but just in case anyone comes across this like me and uses CakePHP 2:

`RequestHandler::isAjax()` is deprecated, use the Request Object's `$this->request->is('ajax');`

More info [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#inspecting-the-request)

Answer (score 3):

Without the use of components you can use something like this:

```
$this->params['isAjax'];
```

This will return a bool.

Answer (score 2):

this is the way whisch is described is doc.I have been using since i started using cakephp

```
if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){
//
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to check the function of the php side, try:

```
$this->log('some debug',LOG_DEBUG);
```

then check app/tmp/logs/debug.log.